# RVO when converting return value

Tags: c++, inheritance, type-conversion, return-value-optimization

I struggle with the complexity of conversions and casting, and I can't find advice online that clearly guarantees efficient conversion on function return. I have two classes, Base and Derived, where Derived has no extra data members over Base. I have a named constructor for the base class that I want to return using RVO and cast to an object of the derived type with as little overhead as possible.

```
class Base { 
public:
    static Base namedConstructor(int n){
        return Base(n);
    } 
protected:
    Base(int n) : member(n){
    }
    int member; 
};

class Derived : public Base  {
    static Derived nC2(int n) {
        Derived derived = namedConstructor(n); 
        // Error: no suitable user-defined conversion from "Base" to "Derived"... 
        // modify derived
        return derived; 
    } 
};
```

Is there a way to fix the error that satisfies all the following requirements?

1. No use of RTTI. Dynamic casting seems unnecessary.
2. Only one definition of namedConstructor in case I need to modify it. If necessary, I can make it a template, but I am interested in the alternatives.
3. namedConstructor should take advantage of RVO in nC2.
4. The conversion should not silently fail if I add or remove data members from either the base or the derived class (something similar to reinterpret_cast may do this).

Comment: You can't convert an object into another like that. The compiler needs to know how to create one from the other. The `Derived` object can't even be constructed as `Base` has a private constructor.

Comment: I made the constructor protected. I'm not sure how to address your other concern. Of course I can't convert and object like that, there is an error.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `private` ctor. to `Derived`, which constructs it from a `Base`:

```
Derived(const Base& base) : Base(base) {
}
```

If later you add extra member variables to `Derived`, initialize them also.

This is standard-compliant (although a little bit weird), and will be optimized away in release builds.

Comment: Thank you, but how does RVO work in the line "Derived derived = namedConstructor(n);"? Say that base has a big array data member consisting of n 0s. How many times will that big array be written on the stack or heap in the line "Derived derived = namedConstructor(n);"? 
 How do you know?

Comment: @cinnamon "The objects are constructed directly into the storage where they would otherwise be copied/moved to." If there is copy elision, it means one time, directly on target storage.

Comment: @cinnamon: The code is optimized quite well, see a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/faYYTs). MSVC calls only `nC2`, clang and gcc optimizes even better.

Answer (score 1):

I've added constructors and with g++ 3.0 there is copy elision:

```
class Base { 
public:
    static Base namedConstructor(int n){
        return Base(n);
    } 
protected:
    Base(int n) : member(n){
        std::cout << "Create Base" << std::endl;
    }
    Base (const Base & b) : member (b.member) {
        std::cout << "Copy Base" << std::endl;
    }
    int member; 
};

class Derived : public Base  {
public:
    Derived () : Base (0) {
        std::cout << "Create Derived" << std::endl;
    }
    Derived (const Base & b) : Base(b) {
        std::cout << "Create Derived from base" << std::endl;
    }
    int val () { return member; }
    static Derived nC2(int n) {
        return namedConstructor(n); //derived; 
    } 
};

int main ()
{
    Derived d = Derived::nC2(1);
    std::cout << "Value: " << d.val() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output from this is:

```
Create Base
Copy Base
Create Derived from base
Value: 1
```

so one `Base` creation, one copy of `Base` when creating `Derived` and the `Derived` itself.

There are no copies from `namedConstructor` exit or `nC2`, nor for the assignment in `main`.

I've compiled this with `-O0` but with those so small functions may be there is optimization here and those are removed.

Comment: Doesn't that copy seem unnecessary? Can I not assume that the derived class and the base class will appear the same in memory?

Comment: perhaps I can phrase this question differently: is there anything smart I can do in the reinterpret_cast direction that still satisfies 4?

Comment: You can't reinterpret correctly a base class to a derived unless it is a pointer or reference. The copy there is because you are converting a base object to a derived one. You can't avoid that with the method you request. The copy is in `Derived (const Base & b) : Base(b) {` the copy is in `Base(b)`, you can't avoid that to convert a `Base` to a `Derived` working with *values* instead of pointers or references.